# How to display devel dpm messages on a panels generated page?

Tags: panels, debugging

I am testing a custom module for a site using Panels Everywhere & Panels. I need to put the results of a Devel module `dpm()` message into a pane so that I can see it on page displays. Does anyone know what content type it might be? I assumed it would be System Help, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside ***panels-pane.tpl.php*** file which is responsible for printing panel pane. 
You can find this on Panels directory but you should better copy this into your theme folder and do there any modifications.

Comment: What code do you refer to?